# A closed noncompact subspace of a metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Say that we have a metric space $X$ and that $Y= \{y_1, y_2,\ldots\}$ is a countable collection of points in $X$ such that for any two points in $Y$, we have $d(y_n, y_m) \geq1$, i.e. the distance between those points is $\geq1$.

We want to show that $Y$ is closed in $X$ and that when equipped with the subspace topology, $Y$ is not compact. Couldn't we go about using contradiction to show the first claim? I'm thinking we could assume $Y$ is not closed in $X$, which would mean that there exists an accumulation point, say $x$ of $Y$, such that $x \notin Y$. How would we go from there? Not exactly sure how to tackle the second part of the question. I guess once the second part is shown, we will in fact have that $X$ is not compact, since every closed subspace of a compact space is compact.

Comment: The current answers seem sufficient to me - I would just add, to really get an idea of what would be useful in the proof, come up with an example using a *real*-ly easy metric space ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each $x\in X$ let $B(x)=\left\{z\in X:d(x,z)<\frac12\right\}$. Show that for each $x\in X$, $B(x)\cap Y$ contains at most one point. Conclude that $Y$ is closed in $X$. Does $\{B(y)\cap Y:y\in Y\}$ have a finite subcover?

Comment: For $Y$ not to be compact in the subspace topology, an open cover must not be able to exhibit a finite subcover. So in answer to your question, I would say no. Just need to see how.

Comment: @Sachin: It follows from the first thing that I suggested you show: that for each $x\in X$ (and therefore certainly for each $x\in Y$) $B(x)\cap Y$ contains at most one point.

Answer (score 3):

**Hints:**

1. Use sequences and their limits.
2. Cover $Y$ by balls of radius $1/2$.

Comment: Using sequences and limits seems more complicated than what is needed.  If you cover $Y$ with balls of radius $1/2$, then no point of $Y$ except the center of the ball is within the ball, and that's enough to show that the center of the ball is not a limit point of $Y$, without thinking about sequences.